# PHP: Since when is HTTP_GET_VARS not working any more?

Tags: php, deprecated

I know that HTTP_GET_VARS is deprecated and $_GET should be used.
But we have an old web shop that still has some HTTP_GET_VARS in the code.
It appears to have worked well until tht PHP update to 7.4.

Have tried to find out since which PHP version HTTP_GET_VARS is actually not working anymore, but without success.

Who knows this? Is it 7.4?

Comment: I would say that it really shouldn't matter. If it doesn't work in PHP 7.4, then you should just go ahead and fix the code. [In 9 days, PHP 7.4 will be the lowest supported PHP version (only getting security updates for another year)](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: It matters to me because I need to find out why things don't work in PHP 7.4 that used to in 7.3. I have fixed the code but the HTTP_GET_VARS issue did not cause the error I was after.

Comment: Then you should read the migration documents for PHP versions... they usually tell the most significant changes between versions and how to migrate your code appropriately.

Comment: _"I have fixed the code but the HTTP_GET_VARS issue did not cause the error I was after"_ - So you have fixed the code and HTTP_GET_VARS wasn't the issue, then I really don't understand why it matters (since the question is specifically about HTTP_GET_VARS which you say wasn't the issue.) What is the actual question here? Are you still using that and want to know when it will stop working?

Comment: @M. Eriksson: The question is what it is: "Since when is HTTP_GET_VARS not working any more?". I have not fixed the code. It matters to me because I want to find out the origins of an error that happened when switching to 7.4, and knowing if HTTP_GET_VARS stopped working exactly in 7.4 would be a great help.

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz: I did, but could not find an answer there

Comment: Seems like it was removed in 5.4 If you check: https://3v4l.org/HiVQR (and select +include eol). You can then see what versions throw undefined errors and what versions doesn't.

Comment: @M. Eriksson: Hey...this is a good WebSite. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz: I do not intend to migrate the code ... I just want to find out why an error was caused.